# Variable length tuples in f#

Tags: f#

Is it possible to write a function to accept a tuple of variable length? I'm trying to write a method that can be called like this:

```
let a = sum(1,2)
let b = sum(1,2,3)
```

EDIT: Could it be interpreted as a function call with params? Or would the method need to be written in c#:

```
double sum(params object[] double) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No - tuples are by definition not variable length, and to write a function like this you'd need something like template metaprogramming in C++ - and there isn't such a thing in F#; `let inline` won't help you there either.

Of course, if you take a list instead, it won't look that much different:

```
sum[1; 2]
sum[1; 2; 3]
```

Comment: Right: My definition of a "variable length tuple" is basically a "list". ;-)

Comment: Except a list is constrained to have the same type for all its elements, whereas tuples can have different types for each. To achieve such a thing for lists, you'd maybe want to make a discrimiated union type with one case for each interesting type for your list, and make the list contain that union type.

Answer (score 4):

@PavelMineav is right, you can't do it, but note that members can be overloaded, a la

```
type Foo() =
    member this.sum(x,y) = x + y
    member this.sum(x,y,z) = x + y + z

let foo = new Foo()
printfn "%d" (foo.sum(1,2))
printfn "%d" (foo.sum(1,2,3))
```

whereas let-bound functions cannot.